# Publish UWP Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, publish

Hello I was trying to make two programs(server and client) on one machine. I did it with WPF and then I tried to do it with UWP, but I didn't succeed. The problem is that the listener in the server is waiting for a connection, but it never comes. This only happens when I try to do the connection from two separate projects. 
If I do it in one project everything works fine. I saw somewhere that it is not possible to run the server and client form one machine with UWP, but the information was not so good explained.
So my question is, is it possible to make two separate projects with UWP for server and client on one computer and if not how can I test the programs(Do I need another computer to test it or there is some other way to do it).
And can someone tell me if there is a possible way to publish my project like the option from Console Applications, so that I can send my client to another computer maybe and try then. All I could find on the internet is how to publish your Apps to the Microsoft Store.

Server

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{        
    string port = "11000";
    string hostv4 = "127.0.0.1";
    StreamSocketListener server;
    public MainPage()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
         StartServer();

    }

    private async void StartServer()
    {

         HostName name = new HostName(hostv4);
         server = new StreamSocketListener();
         server.ConnectionReceived += this.Receive;
         await server.BindEndpointAsync(name, port);                        
         Chat.Content += ("server is listening...\n");//chat is a ScrollViewer where I show the received messsges

    }

    private async void Receive(StreamSocketListener sender, StreamSocketListenerConnectionReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
            string receivedMsg;
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(args.Socket.InputStream.AsStreamForRead()))
            {

                receivedMsg = await sr.ReadLineAsync();
            }

            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => Chat.Content += (string.Format("server received the request: \"{0}\"\n", receivedMsg)));

    }


}
```

Client

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    string port = "11000";
    string hostv4 = "127.0.0.1";
    StreamSocket client;
    public MainPage()
    {
         this.InitializeComponent();
         Connect();
    }

    private async void Connect()
    {
            client = new StreamSocket();
            HostName name = new HostName(hostv4);

            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => Chat.Content += (string.Format("client trying to connect...\n")));
            await client.ConnectAsync(name, port);

            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => Chat.Content += (string.Format("client connected\n")));
       }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            string request = Input.Text; //Input is the name of my TextBox
            using (Stream outputStream = client.OutputStream.AsStreamForWrite())
            {
                using (var sw = new StreamWriter(outputStream))
                {
                    await sw.WriteLineAsync(request);
                    await sw.FlushAsync();
                }
            }

            await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => Chat.Content += (string.Format("client sent request: {0}\n", request)));
     }
```

I also have enabled Internet(Client & Server) and Private Networks(Client & Server) from the Capabilities

Comment: What kind of server/client are you trying to do ? this should not be an issue, there is absolutely nothing wrong about having a server and a client on the same computer, at least for most common protocols like TCP or HTTP.

Comment: its nothing complicated. I tried to make something like a chat. I have a textbox and by clicking a button the input in the box is sent to the server. I used the link(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets) for my project

Comment: Which protocol are you using ?

Comment: I am using tcp/ip from this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets

Comment: So I can confirm you that what you are trying to do is possible. What is your issue exactly ?

Comment: I will edit my post and show you my code in a few minutes.

Comment: maybe the problem is with the bind function in the server or the ports.

Comment: I reproduce the problem by trying your code. I will try to look into it later today

Comment: Is the using StreamSocket a requirement for you? An alternative approach is to use AppServices, which is the "UWP way" of doing inter-process communication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service

Comment: I am trying to do it with AppSerices now, but I can not add a reference to my AppServiceProvider. When I choose ` Add > Reference > Projects > Solution` it says that the list is empty.